# How do I add a separator before a repeating word in a string?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a raw text as shown below:

```
images = "background-image:url('some-url'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image:url('some-url'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image:url('some-url'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image:url('some-url'); background-repeat: no-repeat;"
```

I want to separate the string above such that a comma is inserted before background-image. A result like this.

```
images = "background-image:url('some-url'); background-repeat: no-repeat; , background-image:url('some-url'); background-repeat: no-repeat; , background-image:url('some-url'); background-repeat: no-repeat; , background-image:url('some-url'); background-repeat: no-repeat;"
```

How can I achieve this using python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `replace ()` like this :

```
first_string = "images = background-image:url('some-url'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image:url('some-url'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image:url('some-url'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image:url('some-url'); background-repeat: no-repeat;"
second_string = first_string.replace ('; background-image', '; , background-image')
print (second_string)
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought that there would be another way. But I completely didn't think of this!